# Alternating row color in JSTL with nested loop

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I would like to alternate row color for each row, I know how to alternate row color using varStatus in a forEach loop. However now, I've a nested loop.

```
<c:forEach var="aPermission" items="${Permissions}" varStatus="loop1">
    <c:forEach var="anIpRange" items="${aPermission.ipRanges}" varStatus="loop2">
    <tr class="${loop2.index % 2 == 0 ? 'row0' : 'row1'}"> [...]
    </c:forEach>
</c:forEach>
```

The code above is using only 'loop2' varStatus, and is only an approximation. How to solve the problem? I've to introduce my count variable or there are better ways?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply use a dedicated counter:

```
<c:set var="counter" value="${0}"/>
<c:forEach var="aPermission" items="${Permissions}" varStatus="loop1">
    <c:forEach var="anIpRange" items="${aPermission.ipRanges}" varStatus="loop2">
        <tr class="${counter % 2 == 0 ? 'row0' : 'row1'}"> [...] </tr>
        <c:set var="counter" value="${counter + 1}"/>
    </c:forEach>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: I tried and it works, thank you. I was wondering if it's really necessary to say value="${0}" instead of just value="0". Is that about the data type, number vs string? Because I tried also with value="0" and still works.

Comment: It works, but it seems more logical to me to use ${0}, because I find that the type of the expression is more obvious.

Answer (score 2):

- store a sum of all iterated items (using `<c:set>`). You can do this in the outer loop by calculating `currentSum = currentSum + fn:length(aPermission.ipRanges)`. Do this after the inner loop
- use `currentSum + loop2.index` to check the color for each row.

Comment: This would work, but seems more complicated than using a dedicated counter.

Answer (score 1):

There is an 1-line way.

**UPD**. I have been mistaken first time. there is the right solution without redundant variables.

```
<tr class="${(loop2.index*fn:length(aPermission.ipRanges) + loop1.index) % 2 == 0 ? 'row0' : 'row1'}">
```

Comment: I thought about it, but this way doesn't work, because for instance: loop1 starts at 0 and loop2 starts at 0, 0+0=0, second row loop1 is 0, loop2 is 1, 1+0=1, third row loop1 is 1, loop2 is 0, 0+1=1. arghh two consecutive rows with the same color.

Comment: Sorry, this won't work either, because you're assuming that every permission has the same number of ipRanges, which isn't true. It could have any number from 1 up, and each Permission can have a different number of them. Thank you for trying to help anyway!

Comment: Ah. Then counter is really necessary :)